# Play framework akka remote version

Tags: playframework, akka, playframework-2.2, akka-remote-actor

I'm using play framework 2.2.2, and I want to add Akka remote library. Which versions are compatible?

Can I use Akka remote 2.3.3?

==== Update

I'm adding akka remote dependency:

```
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-remote" % "2.2.4"
```

Do I have to change akka version in play framework?

Comment: For a wider question on akka remote compatibility, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29501403/how-binary-compatible-is-distributed-akka/29508065

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Play 2.2.x is compatible with Akka 2.2.x. Play 2.3.x is compatible with Akka 2.3.x.
(It is a coincident that the version numbers are the same.)

Comment: But I would like to use Akka Sharding which I think is only available in Akka 2.3.x.  It's a shame that Play doesn't do a good job of being backwards compatible.  May last two experiences have been a pain to upgrade.

Comment: then you have to use Play 2.3.x